# Битовая строка

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер!
Можете ли объяснить?
Дали очень сложное задание, не могу его понять.

> Определить класс заданного типа. Написать определенные как
> дружественные функции подпрограммы ввода с клавиатуры и вывода на экран данных,
> определяющих объекты этого класса. Перегрузить указанные операции и функции с
> помощью составных функций класса. Определить конструкторы и деструктор.

Битовая строка

```
<, > ==
long abs()
```

- сравнения величин
- проверка на равенство
- значение числа, определяемого битовой строкой

Comment: Жуть какая-то.

Comment: Я пишу на PHP и на С++ начал хорошо,не привык жаловатся но я не встречался с таким никогда.

Comment: Иногда у технарей отечественной школы напрочь отсутствует способность ясно излагать мысли

Comment: Есть такая книжка Абрамян 1001 задача,так вот ее просто решать,матрицы ,массивы итд. А вот то что дано выше это архи-непонятное.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Задание действительно сформулировано не очень подробно, но догадаться, в принципе, можно.*

- **Битовая строка** - не самая удачная калька с обширно используемого термина `bitfield`. Для большего понимания рекомендую ознакомится с [**вот этим**](http://mech.math.msu.su/~shvetz/54/inf/perl-problems/chBitSet_sFurtherImprovements.xhtml) референсом и, например, с [**std::bitset.**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/)
- Определите, вызывает ли у Вас вопросы *общая постановка задания,* и если да, то необходимо с каждым пунктом разбираться отдельно.

> - Определить класс заданного типа.
> - Написать определенные как дружественные функции подпрограммы ввода с клавиатуры и вывода на экран данных, определяющих объекты этого класса.
> - Перегрузить указанные операции и функции с помощью составных функций класса.
> - Определить конструкторы и деструктор.

Теперь чуть подробнее об операциях, которые Вам необходимо реализовать *(помимо `operator<<` и `operator>>`, неявно указанных в пункте 2 предыдущей части).*

- **`<, > ==`**

> Здесь, очевидно, Вас просят ввести некоторое отношение порядка [**(strict weak ordering)**](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) на множестве битовых строк. Задача сформулирована плохо, поскольку таких отношений можно придумать достаточное количество и они никак не отражены в самом тексте задания. *Возможно, что (учитывая следующую часть задания) достаточно просто реализовать сравнение соответствующих чисел.*

- **`long abs()`** - "значение числа, определяемого битовой строкой"

> Предположительно, здесь нужно получить число, которое в своей *двоичной форме* и записано в Вашей строке. То есть, скажем, битовая строка `11001` будет соответствовать числу `25`.

Comment: Ооо спасибо!
А вот не подскажете почему MVS C++ 6.0 ругается на randomize() и random() обозначает как необъявленную переменную.

Comment: Потому что `rand()` :)

Comment: Заменил на rand() и выводит что у функций не заданы параметры.
Хотел выложить что получилось ,кодировка не позволяет .

Comment: @gold Моя интуиция подсказывает мне, что с реализацией всех пунктов этого задания у вас будут неплохие траблы))

Comment: Я написал код,но незнаю как его выложить,чуток изменить его надо )
Да траблы конечно есть,преподователь будет страдать от количества вопросов...

Comment: По сути это битовые поля в Си и С++. Можно взять за основу при создании класса и дальше особых траблов не вижу.

Сначала я подумал, что речь идет о битовых строках (реально упакованых) произвольной длины. Но потом решил, что данный ответ правильно отражает суть дела.

@gold, выложить код лучше, наверное, прямо здесь, используя "правка" Вашего вопроса.

Comment: @avp вставляю но он как то криво отображает.

Comment: @gold, вставляете парочку пустых строк, потом Paste код, выделяете его и кликаете в "кнопку" 101010 над окошком с впросом. Потом еще пустую строчку и можно писать дальше.